# Loading map pins from firebase onto mapkit in swift for all users to be able to see

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit, mapkitannotation

Im creating a tagging app, where a user can tag street art to a map, this information is then available for all users to see.

I can upload my data to Firebase however Im struggling being able to pull this data back down to appear on the map as an annotation.

[Firebase Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m88qC.png)

I have created a loadCustomAnnotations() to load up the database information as a pin on my map, I know I need to observe the values and just load in the "art" path, and loop over all the results however I cant seem to turn this into an annotation! can anyone help?! thanks.

```
func loadCustomLocations() {

    FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "art")

    let artPin = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "art")

    artPin.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in


        for item in snapshot.children {
            guard let snapshot = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }

            let ref = art(snapshot: snapshot)

            print(snapshot)

            self.artDrops.append(ref)

     //       self.makeAnnotation(artDrops: art)


        }
    })
}
```

}

this function now prints all my locations i just need to know how to turn this into an annotation!

[Printing Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMlPb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you are now able to upload and get back all you locations, the following steps won't be so hard. Just using .addAnnotations and you are good to go!

```
let artAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            var artDrops = [CLLocation]()
            for location in artDrops{
            artAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
            artAnnotation.title = "your location title"
            mapView.addAnnotations([artAnnotation])
            }
```

Comment: Thank you this worked with a bit of editing! Thanks for explaining it too made it so much clearer!

Comment: Willing to help : )